# How do I select an array from the results of a query?

Tags: arrays, oracle, subquery, aggregate, varray

I've created a VARRAY type:

```
CREATE TYPE my_array AS varray(1024) OF VARCHAR2(512);
```

I know I can create an instance of `my_array` from a list of values using `my_array()`:

```
SELECT my_array('foo', 'bar');
```

But is there a way to create an instance from the results of a query? I'm thinking something like this:

```
SELECT my_array(SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE owner = 'SCOTT')
  FROM dual;
```

Or, failing that, an aggregate that returns a `my_array`:

```
SELECT my_array_agg(table_name) FROM all_tables WHERE owner = 'SCOTT';
```

Is this do-able in Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulk collect in plsql

```
declare 
arr my_array;
begin 
SELECT table_name bulk collect into arr FROM all_tables WHERE owner = 'SCOTT';
end;
```

or

```
select collect(table_name) from all_tables where owner = 'SCOTT';
```

but you cant do anything with a collection like that in sqlplus.

Comment: Fortunately for me, I use [the DBI](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI), and the [Oracle Driver knows](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD::Oracle#OBJECT-COLLECTION-DATA-TYPES) to convert collections to arrays. Makes me wonder, though: Can I define a column as storing the result of a `COLLECT()`? Or must it be a VARRAY?

Comment: have you tried casting ....  `select cast(collect(col) as my_array) from ... `  ?

Comment: Yes, that works fine. I meant not having to create a type, but just the object returned by `collect()` as the column type. That does not appear to be do-able.

Comment: you have two build in array types in `dbms_utility` - see it you can use them.